# Can I store beer in wine bottles

Tags: beer, bottling, priming, pressure, bottle-bomb

I have only standard wine bottles available, are they strong enough to hold bottle primed beer (max. 30 psi) without exploding?

Comment: Jwbradley is totally correct here.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with JesseB1234 and Mr_road.

I did it myself a few times and results may vary. I had one cork poping up out of 5 bottles.  It is not ideal, but if you have no other option, here are a few tips :

- Use short corks, they may be more permeable
- Do not overfill, leave a bit of space (not too much either)
- Do not bottle condition too hot, slower bottle conditionning is less prone to pop
- Use a shrink wrap plastic cap to help secure the cork in (champagne cork is best)
- Use a bit less priming sugar

Personnally, I consider a plastic Soda/Coke bottle a better option.

Comment: I second soda bottles, they are very resistant to pressure. I have used them for both beer and sparkling fruit wines. Is also amusing when someone thinks you are pouring coke and get sparking plum wine instead :)

Answer (score 3):

The bottles will probably be fine, although they are not made for being under pressure so don’t take my word for it.

But how do you want to close them off? Corks without some sort of cage will pop out over time due to the pressure inside and the necks of wine bottles are not made for crown caps.

Answer (score 3):

I have done so before and it was OK, but... you do run the risk of them blowing up.

If you do close them off I would cork them and leave them pointing up, so hopefully the corks would pop before the bottle, and as pointing up would not flood your storage area.

Best to use champagne bottles.

Answer (score 2):

No, standard wine bottles are not meant to hold much pressure at all. Less than one atmosphere and then will easily break. Believe me, I've had wine that was barely fizzy and bottles started to pop. Plus there is no way to hold the pressure back unless you use screw caps. Better to find 22oz beer bottles or sparkling wine bottles. Hang out at your local recycling facility and pick up all the free bottles you want.

Answer (score 2):

I thought about using wine bottles, but then I discovered that you can put a cap onto champagne bottles using a 29mm cap. However, you will need a capper that allows you to swap the bell to 29mm.